# CSS nested grids dont fit in eachother

Tags: html, css, nested, css-grid

Hello recently I have started to mengle with css's display:grid as it offers more flexibility.The problem at hand is that I use nested grids and they don't fit in eachother as provided in the example.
In the image below the green grid should fit inside the red grid left column but it doesn't.  I don't understand why it behaves like this.Can you  provide some explanations please?

[image]

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins',sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
}

body{
    background: lightblue;
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-direction: column;
   
    margin: 50px;
}

/* 595 x 842 px. 72ppi */
/* 96 PPI – 794 x 1123 
/*150 PPI – 1240 x 1754 */
.container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 25% 75%;
    grid-template-rows: 100%;
    grid-template-areas: "left right";
    grid-gap: 10px;
    min-height: 842px;height: 842px;
    min-width:595px;width: 595px;
    background-color:white;
    padding-top: 75px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
   
}

    .left{
        grid-area: left;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas: 
        "contact"
        "skills"
        "skills"
        "skills"
        "languages";
        grid-gap: 10px;
        font-size:1rem;

    }

        .contact{
            grid-area: contact;
            word-wrap: break-word;
       
        }

        .contact>h2::before{
            content: "\2022";
        }


        .skills{
            grid-area: skills;
        }

        .languages{
            grid-area: languages;
        }


    .right{
        grid-area: right;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas:
        "intro"
        "history"
        "history"
        "history"
        "education"
        "about";
        grid-gap: 10px;
    }

        .intro{
            grid-area: intro;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-areas: 
            "photo name name name"
            "content content content content";
        }

            .photo{
                grid-area: photo;
            }

            .name{
                grid-area: name;
            }

            .content{
                grid-area: content;
            }

            
        .history{
            grid-area: history;
        }

        .education{
            grid-area: education;
        }

        .about{
            grid-area: about;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="contact">
                <h2>Contact</h2>
                <p>
                    <span class="fa-stack fa-sm">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x" style="color:rgb(0, 100, 230);"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-flag fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                    </span>
                    124124124124
                </p> 

                <p>
                    <span class="fa-stack fa-sm">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x" style="color:rgb(0, 100, 230);"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-flag fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                    </span>
                    124124124214
                </p> 

                <p>
                    <span class="fa-stack fa-sm">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x" style="color:rgb(0, 100, 230);"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-flag fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                    </span>
                    111111111111111111111111111112222222222222222222222211111111111
                </p> 
                
                <p>
                    <span class="fa-stack fa-sm">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x" style="color:rgb(0, 100, 230);"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-flag fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                    </span>
                    12312412412412412414
                </p> 
            </div>
            <div class="skills"></div>
            <div class="languages"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="intro">
                <div class="photo"></div>
                <div class="name"></div>
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="history"></div>
            <div class="education"></div>
            <div class="about"></div>
        </div>
    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Main problem here is your long p tag.
I don't think this is your destinated content.
Simply, when You'll have "normal" words You can use "word-wrap:wrap;"
But in scenario with many numbers You can simply use `<br>` tags inside your`<p>`  text.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9mnja052/)

Comment: yeah, <br/> is not the way you want to fix stuff

Comment: That's why i wrote about word-wrap.